Oracle Apex CLOB Item throws cannot convert datatype 11 to varchar 2 |PL/SQL Numeric error
I have an IG with CLOB column item.
For processing of clob data following code is being used:
DECLARE
  LO_CLOB        CLOB;
  LO_CHUNK_SIZE  NUMBER := 4000;
BEGIN
  SELECT DESCRIPTION 
  INTO   LO_CLOB 
  FROM   T_EMPLOYEE
  WHERE  EMP_ID = apex_application.g_x01;

  IF lo_clob IS NOT NULL THEN
    FOR i IN 0 .. FLOOR(LENGTH(LO_CLOB)/LO_CHUNK_SIZE )
    LOOP
      SYS.HTP.PRN(SUBSTR(LO_CLOB, i * LO_CHUNK_SIZE + 1, LO_CHUNK_SIZE ));
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
/

One of the clob files has value exceeding 32k, i.e. around 265k characters.
So i am getting PL/SQL Numeric error on report page:
COLUMN DESCRIPTION which is of Datatype 11 cannot be converted to varchar2.
How can this be handled?

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data to allow us to replicate the problem. At the moment, I am not able to replicate the issue fiddle and the Oracle Data-Type documentation does not list a type with code 11.

There is a fiddle from oen of my previous questions that used same code and was answered by you.. There it was about handling NULLS. Here its about a clob file which is 256k and hence throwing PL/SQL numeric error. Can you please look into this if possible? I am unable to share the clob file..https://dbfiddle.uk/0Vvm3VTw

The mistake in that fiddle is that you insert the text into the emp_name column and not the description column and you end up with FOR i IN 0 .. NULL LOOP. If you fix the columns in the INSERT then the code works fiddle. Can you add a [MRE] that actually replicates your error?

In fiddle its failing if i try inserting clob data with 256k+ characters
